# Invariance of Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, covariance

How exactly does the variational approach make it clear that the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion will have exactly the same form no matter what coordinate system we use as long as it is done with respect to an inertial frame?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we need inertial frames in Lagrangian mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/99923/)

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118768/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280143/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Please define acronyms and abbreviations on first use if there is any chance that it could be unfamiliar.  Even in subjects.  It's to your advantage to do so. Some people won't even bother to open the question.